# Bubble Sort gives random placement

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I am using a bubble sort to sort descending order of 6 rent values.
However, it keeps spitting out random assortments of the data. I've compared it to other bubble sorts and cannot determine why mine is not putting it in the correct order.

Code below:

```
void sortArray(int *rent, int size) {

    bool swap;
    int temp;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (; count < (size - 1); count++) {
            if (*(rent + count) < *(rent + count + 1))
            {
                temp = rent[count];
                *(rent + count) = rent[count + 1];
                *(rent + count + 1) = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << *(rent + count) << " ";
    cout << "\n";

}
```

Comment: use your debugger on a small case

Comment: As soon as you get two items where the first isn't less than the second, `swap` will be left as `false`, the do...while loop will exit, and the remainder of the array will be left unsorted.

Comment: Why do you use, pointer and array notation interleaved? It makes it only harder to understand your own code?

Comment: Closing this, too much noise.

Comment: I've seen plenty of bubble sorts, back in my high school and college days. This doesn't look like any bubble sort I've ever seen. Time to go back to the fundamentals...

Answer (score 2):

I know eveyone is getting frustrated with your code but actually it is sorting, so cheer up. your only mistake is you are not resetting counter in each outer-loop iteration. This one works fine, check `for` loop header !

```
void sortArray(int *rent, int size) {

    bool swap;
    int temp;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (count=0; count < (size - 1); count++) {
            if (*(rent + count) < *(rent + count + 1))
            {
                temp = rent[count];
                *(rent + count) = rent[count + 1];
                *(rent + count + 1) = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << *(rent + count) << " ";
    cout << "\n";

}
```